# VSTS Ultimate not running all users in load test

Tags: load-testing, visualstudio

I have a Web Performance test created in VSTS Ultimate 2013 with Record feature of the tool. This test involves the below mentioned scenario:-

1. Login to application
2. Navigate to the Search Page
3. Open Create New Page
4. Enter Data and Save record (at this point an entry is created in Database too)

I have added Validation Rule (Finding Username, which is displayed on page header once record save operation is completes) in this test, just to make sure that record is saved and web test is working fine, all the test data (like Name, Address etc.) is coming from CSV file. Now, when I run this test it executes well and assertion (Find Username) works fine. Entry is there in Database too.

Now, I have created a load test in VSTS Ultimate which is using this web test and specified the user load as 5 with constant load pattern and Iteration count as 1, this test case still creates only 1 entry in Database while I have 5 rows with different dataset in CSV file. But if I increase the number of Iterations from 1 to 5, then it creates 5 records; which is a bit confusing. Why VSTS Ultimate is not creating 5 records with constant load as 5, why it is creating only 1 record for 5 user load.

First I thought that application might not be able to handle 2 concurrent user load but if that had been the case then I should get Assertion Failed error or some other error which is not there.

**What could be the possible reason for this behavior of load pattern? Do I need to change anything or I'm missing something in my tests?**

Answer (score 1):

As the iteration count is 1 only one test case is executed.

Both the scenario and the run settings provide an iteration count. Both relate to number of test cases executed. See [this Microsoft blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406973.aspx) for some more information.

Set the iteration count in the scenario to 0 (ie zero) to let the values in the run settings control the number of tests executed. Then in the run settings select between a test that runs for a period of time (with `Use test iterations == False`) or a test that executes a number of test cases (with `Use test iterations == True`).

For example. To have each of the 5 virtual users run (on average) 3 tests, set the iteration count in the run settings to 15 and the iteration count in the scenario to either 0 or 15. Alternatively set the iteration count in the scenario to 15 and in the run settings specify a test duration long enough to run 3 tests one after another.

---

The original question had several references to Coded UI, hence the answer below.

Only one Coded UI test can be run at a time on one computer. Coded UI takes over the mouse, keyboard and screen of the computer while the test executes. To run a test with 10 users doing Coded UI tests at the same time will need 10 agent computers (they can be real or virtual, or a mix).

See, for example [this Microsoft blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gautamg/2009/12/14/is-coded-ui-test-under-load-test-supported/) for more details.

Comment: I think you mis understood my question I am not executing UI test, I am creating performance test and using it in load test. When one execute web performance test with extension .webtest or load test with extension .loadtest then Coded UI doesn't take over the mouse, keyboard etc.

Comment: @Dhiman Your question states that you have a Coded UI test and are running it as part of a load test. If your test was not created using Coded UI then please explain why you mention Coded UI in the question title, in the tags, and more than once in the question's body.

Comment: I got your point and the root cause of confusion. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. Iteration = number of times whole load test needs to be executed and Users = number of Virtual Users/Threads VSTS needs to start to put load on server. If I have 1 test case in my load test (which is the current case, as I have only 1 performance test inside load test) and set the number of users to 5 with Iterations = 2, then as per my understanding VSTS should execute whole test 2 times with 5 virtual user load in each iteration. Which is not happening. I will go through mentioned link in your post but want to confirm if my understanding mentioned is correct?

Comment: @Dhiman No, definitely not. For Visual Studio load tests one iteration means the running of one test case. Please read the detailed Microsoft documents, I cited them for good reasons.

Comment: "Based on my observation". I have gone through the documentation provided by you. Also, I did some play around with load test config. (No. of users, Scenario Iterations and Test Iterations in Runsettings). Based on that I found that "at the end" it doesn't matter how many users I specified, complete load test (1 scenario & 1 test case) only executes the number of times specified in either Scenario Iterations or Test Iterations & that too which ever is lesser. No. of users lesser or greater than Iterations doesn't affect the test execution final result (rows created in DB).

Comment: I added a new question related to this, but as I am asking something different so created new one. http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18055/load-test-configuration-in-vsts-2013